# What does "Human eyes glare at each other, yours and theirs, desperate and resentful down on the pond bottom" mean?

Tags: grammar

The following sentence is from [an article in The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/features/thumb-novels-mobile-phone-fiction-1763849.html):

> Human eyes glare at each other, yours and theirs, desperate and resentful down on the pond bottom.

This is my effort:

> Human eyes glare at each other. Their eyes stare at your eyes and your eyes stare at their eyes. These people are feeling desperate and resentful on the bottom.

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.  From the context of the story, **all** the people trying to escape from misery by living with the carp are still miserable (YOU included.)